# How can we sort array object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort a object array as per colors.

My code:

```js
const colors = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": true
   
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": false
  },
{
    "color": "green",
    "type": true
  },
{
    "color": "black",
    "type": false
  },
{
    "color": "pink",
    "type": true
  }]
  

const list = colors.sort((a) => a.color);
console.log(list);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: I want to alphabetically sort.

Comment: You need a compare function returning the compare result (0, negative, positive). See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in JavaScript takes in a callback with two parameters.

From MDN,

| compareFn(a, b) return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| > 0 | sort a after b |
| < 0 | sort a before b |
| === 0 | keep original order of a and b |

However, instead of writing your own comparison function, you can use the builtin [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare two strings.

```js
const colors = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": true
   
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": false
  },
{
    "color": "green",
    "type": true
  },
{
    "color": "black",
    "type": false
  },
{
    "color": "pink",
    "type": true
  }]
  

const list = colors.sort((a, b) => a.color.localeCompare(b.color));
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will help you to sort in asc order based on color value.

```js
 const colors = [
      {
        "color": "purple",
        "type": true
       
      },
      {
        "color": "red",
        "type": false
      },
      {
        "color": "green",
        "type": true
      },
      {
        "color": "black",
        "type": false
      },
      {
        "color": "pink",
        "type": true
      }
    ]
    
    const sortedColors = colors.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.color < b.color) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.color > b.color) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    
    console.log(sortedColors);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will work.

You can change condition as per requirement, Thanks.

```js
const colors = [{
    "color": "purple",
    "type": true

  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": false
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "type": true
  },
  {
    "color": "black",
    "type": false
  },
  {
    "color": "pink",
    "type": true
  }
]

const result = colors.sort((a, b) => (a.color > b.color) ? 1 : ((b.color > a.color) ? -1 : 0))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `sort()`, you want to **compare two elements** in the array, so you need to put two parameters in there.

```js
const colors = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": true
   
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": false
  },
{
    "color": "green",
    "type": true
  },
{
    "color": "black",
    "type": false
  },
{
    "color": "pink",
    "type": true
  }]
  

const list = colors.sort((a, b) => a.color > b.color);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: but this is not sorting alphabetically

Comment: For more precise sorting, you're probably better off using the `localeCompare` method.